# App Engine Servlet: how to parse a request body containing a JSON-encoded message?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, servlets, google-cloud-storage

I use the Cloud Storage Object Change Notification to notify my App Engine server that a new file has been uploaded. The Object Change Notification is sent as a POST request to a servlet in App Engine.

The body of the request contains a JSON-encoded message as shown in the following example of notification request, directly copied from Google Documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification):

```
{
"kind": "storage#object",
"id": "BucketName/ObjectName",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BucketName/o/ObjectName",
"name": "ObjectName",
"bucket": "BucketName",
"generation": "1367014943964000",
"metageneration": "1",
"contentType": "binary/octet-stream",
"updated": "2013-04-26T22:22:23.832Z",
"size": "10",
"md5Hash": "xHZY0QLVuYng2gnOQD90Yw==",
"mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BucketName/o/ObjectName?generation=1367014943964000&alt=media",
....
}
```

My question is what would be the best solution for parsing the JSON content to java object(s)? I guess the best would be to use a library like e.g. Google gson, but is there any one particularly recommended to be used with App Engine? Or any other better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the library that you know. The differences between well-known libraries become significant when you have mission-critical tasks executed millions of times.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've used the Google gson library and since I only want to parse a couple of elements of the JSON I've used the following code:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(req.getReader()).getAsJsonObject();
String objectName = obj.get("name").getAsString();
String objectBucket = obj.get("bucket").getAsString();
```

It works perfectly.